# How to get all td values and put in array

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I have one table that I need to read td values and put in array so that I then can write to database.

Table looks like this:

```
<table class="maintable" width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th width="100px">Client</th>
        <th width="70px">version</th>
        <th width="120px">ip</th>
        <th width="110px">Connected</th>
        <th width="60px">TotalEcm</th>
        <th width="90px">AcceptedEcm</th>
        <th width="90px">EcmOK</th>
        <th width="50px">EcmTime</th>
        <th>Last used share</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="alt3" colspan="9"> CCcam 1 (338)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Row1" class="alt1" onmouseover="setupdateRow(1)" onmouseout="setupdateRow(0)"> 
        <td>
            <a href="/cccamclient?id=1">CLIENTNAME#1</a>
        </td>
        <td>CCcam 2.0.11<br>419a6380d63b8aec</td>
        <td><img src="/flag_USA.gif" title="United States"> 63.15.11.121</td>
        <td class="online">00d 00:08:16<table class="connect_data">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Successful Login: 1</td>
                    <td>Aborted Connections: 0</td>
                    <td>Total Zapping: 0</td>
                    <td>Channel Freeze: 0</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td align="center">0</td>
        <td>
            <span style="float: right;">0%</span>
        </td>
        <td><span style="float: right;">0%</span></td>
        <td align="center">-- ms</td>
        <td> <span style="float:right;">
            <img title="disable" src="disable.png" onclick="imgrequest('/cccamclient?action=disable&amp;id=1',this);">
            <img title="Debug" src="debug.png" onclick="imgrequest('/cccamclient?action=debug&amp;id=1',this);"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Row2" class="alt2" onmouseover="setupdateRow(2)" onmouseout="setupdateRow(3)"> 
        <td>
            <a href="/cccamclient?id=2">CLIENTNAME#2</a>
        </td>
        <td>CCcam 2.0.11<br>419a6380d63b8aec</td>
        <td><img src="/flag_AT.gif" title="Austria"> 69.75.11.121</td>
        <td class="online">00d 00:08:16<table class="connect_data">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Successful Login: 1</td>
                    <td>Aborted Connections: 0</td>
                    <td>Total Zapping: 0</td>
                    <td>Channel Freeze: 0</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td align="center">0</td>
        <td>
            <span style="float: right;">0%</span>
        </td>
        <td><span style="float: right;">0%</span></td>
        <td align="center">-- ms</td>
        <td> <span style="float:right;">
            <img title="disable" src="disable.png" onclick="imgrequest('/cccamclient?action=disable&amp;id=2',this);">
            <img title="Debug" src="debug.png" onclick="imgrequest('/cccamclient?action=debug&amp;id=1',this);"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

So I need when echo from array this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => CLIENTNAME#1
            [1] => CCcam 2.0.11
            [2] => 419a6380d63b8aec
            [3] => /flag_USA.gif
            [4] => United States
            [5] -> 63.15.11.121
            [6] -> 00d 00:08:16
            [7] -> Successful Login: 1
            [8] -> Aborted Connections: 0
            [9] -> Total Zapping: 0
            [10]-> Channel Freeze: 0
            [11]->
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => CLIENTNAME#2
            [1] => CCcam 2.0.11
            [2] => 419a6380d63b8aec
            [3] => /flag_AT.gif
            [4] => Austria
            [5] -> 69.75.11.121
            [6] -> 00d 00:08:16
            [7] -> Successful Login: 1
            [8] -> Aborted Connections: 0
            [9] -> Total Zapping: 0
            [10]-> Channel Freeze: 0
            [11]->
        )
)
```

How to get desired results? I tried with `$dom = new domDocument;` but I could not get what I need from table into array. If some one could give simple code on jsfiddle.

Comment: You would need to establish more rules.  For example '<td>CCcam 2.0.11<br>419a6380d63b8aec</td>' is split into two records in your example, but your spec is to extract each td content as a string.

Comment: Can you plese give some code to start with? Because i im not familiar with this td i read tutorials on google but i don't get what i need. Thanks

Comment: I do not think you have understood my previous comment.  Your spec is to extract stuff between <td> and </td> but in your sample output you have also split on <BR>.  If you can clarify?

Comment: here is the code i try but unsucessfull: http://codepad.org/uOBcv6W8

Comment: There is a fundamental problem with your quoting of HTML code which only becomes obvious if you use the code in your codepad example.  In the example on this site, it is not obvious as the HTML is not being put into a string.  Will post an answer shortly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dom = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML(str_replace('<br>', urlencode('<br>'), $html));
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
```

Untill here your code is true :) then correcting

```
// set condition that attribute id is present 
//else some first tr will be received too
$rows = $xpath->query('//tr[@id]'); 

$array_multics = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $tmp = array();
// select what you want. If I missed something, add to xpath
  foreach ( $xpath->query('.//td/text() | .//td/a/text() | .//td/img/@src', $row) as $col)  {
    $value = trim($col->nodeValue);
//exclude `-- ms` and many empty values
    if(!empty($value) && (strpos($value, '-- ms') === false))
// split <br> which comes from dom as `%3Cbr%3`
      foreach (explode('%3Cbr%3', $value) as $val) 
        $tmp[] = $val;  // here all you want
  }
  $array_multics[] = $tmp;
}
```

Array will be indexed by number as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is only obvious if you look at the code example posted in the comment above - http://codepad.org/uOBcv6W8 - your HTML string quoting is wrong.

You can use heredoc (now called newdoc) syntax to quote your HTML with embedded quotes, e.g. (from https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)

```
<?php
$str = <<<'EOD'
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using nowdoc syntax.
EOD;
```